# jenkins slave run in jdk 1.6

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-agent

i have a very complex environment in my jenkins build and deployment. There are four kinds of system: windows(for the jboss java environment), aix(for the xlc compiler), linux(for the websphere jee application), mac (for the ios development). Different system own their jdk, the least one is the JDK 1.6. For the AIX IBM JDK(with the DES SDK problem), so i need the jenkins 2.32.1+, but my environment which has the JDK 1.6, so the slave JNLP gos wrong. But the jenkins slave jar need the JDK 1.7+, so i thinks weather i can compile the slave jar by myself for the jdk 1.6.

How can i solve this problem?  I just want to support the IBM JDK and the jdk 1.6.Or there are the source code for the slave.jar, i just compile the whole one for the jdk 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can still support builds on a 1.6 version of java while running the slave on 1.7. Add the appropriate 1.6 tools in your Jenkins config, but just make sure to execute your slave.jar from a compatible version of Java.

Comment: my slave machine is the JDK 1.6. But the jenkins slave.jar support only the 1.6. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Where  to config to use slave.jar for JDK 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

In you execute shell just define JAVA_HOME=. This ways you can use jdk6 for compilation without conflicting sith Jnlp whichcan point to jdk7